# list of dictionary compare first value of first dict with first value of next dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, for example:

```
l = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}, {"a":1, "b":2, "c":4}, {"a":1, "b":7, "c":4}, {"a":2, "b":7, "c":4}]
```

I need to create a nested dictionary if value of "a" are equal.
I have tried:

```
l2 = [l[i] for i in range(len(l)-1) if l[i].get('a') == l[i+1].get('a')]
d = {"element"+ str(index): x for index, x in enumerate(l2, start=1)}
```

But in the output, I'm getting it skips one element:

```
{'element1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 'element2': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}}
```

Expected output:

```
{'element1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 'element2': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}, 'element3': {"a":1, "b":7, "c":4}}
```

Could someone please help me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: pleas add the expected output

Comment: Please show the expected output first and then the attempt.

Comment: Are you aware that the expected output has a syntax error?

Comment: What is the code without comprehension? It will be easier to understand and reproduce your issue

Comment: "create a nested dictionary if value of "a" are equal" - this is still ambiguous description, please be more precise. What if there are more "a" value repetitions, etc.?

Comment: Why are you putting a 1 if the value of a in the 4th element of l is 2?

Comment: What do you refer as "create a nested dictionary if value of 'a' are equal"? Create it for the most common value? Create one dict for each value of `a`? Not create anything if not all values are the same?

Comment: `l=[{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}, {"a":1, "b":2, "c":4}, {"a":1, "b":7, "c":4}, {"a":2, "b":7, "c":4}]
d={}
l2=[]
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i].get('a') == l[i+1].get('a'):
        l2.append(l[i])
for index, x in enumerate(l2, start=1):
    d["element " + str(index)] = [x]`                                                                                                   @12944qwerty here is without  comprehension

Comment: @RunTheGauntlet added output I expect for more clarification.

Comment: @GusSL added output I axpect for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
out = {f'element{i + 1}': j for i, j in enumerate(l) if any(j['a'] == k['a'] for k in l[:i] + l[i+1:])}
```

Output:

```
{'element1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 'element2': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}, 'element3': {'a': 1, 'b': 7, 'c': 4}}
```

Comment: thanks, but only need an elements if value of a is the same, in this case 3. Fourth element with 'a':4 should be filtered out.

Comment: returns an error __string indices must be integers__ unfortunetly...